# Противоречит ли реализация нескольких интерфейсов одним классом принципам SOLID

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, интерфейс, solid

Вопрос немного философский. Для начала 1 и 4 принципы SOLID из `wiki`:

> Существует лишь одна причина, приводящая к изменению класса.

и

> Много интерфейсов, специально предназначенных для клиентов, лучше, чем один интерфейс общего назначения.

Иначе говоря - один класс должен выполнять свою узко-направленную задачу и никакие другие.  Тоже и интерфейс - лучше разделять один общий интерфейс(аналог класса "помойки") на составные, содержащие обьявления полей и методов необходимых для выполнения своей конкретной задачи, причем только одной. Из 1+4 принципов можно сделать вывод, что один класс должен реализовывать 1 интерфейс что бы не противоречить 1 принципу. Если же 1 класс реализует несколько интерфейсов, то следовательно обязан реализовать выполнение нескольких задач что никак не вяжется с 1 принципом.

Есть ли здесь противоречие, или я неправильно понял эти принципы (если да, то прошу обьяснить где именно)?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский смотря какие задачи возложены на класс `FileLoger`. Если это ведение журнала ошибок то что он должен read()?

Comment: Есть класс XMLSerializer, есть JSONSerializer, есть BananaSerializer. Есть интерфейсы IReadable с методом read и IWritable с методом write. Все эти классы реализуют эти интерфейсы, эти методы, но выполняют свою конкретную функцию по работе с конкретными данными... Ничего противоречивого тут нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Выполняют `свою конкретную функцию` - запись и чтение это разные функции а значит и причины для изменения класса 2.

Comment: Они выполняют работу с xml, json и бананами соответственно. Это их назначения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хотите сказать, что вопрос сводится только к тому, что считать `функцией`? т.е. 1 функция(работать с json) = чтение(json) + запись(json) или 1 функция(( работать с json)) = только чтение((json))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если же 1 класс реализует несколько интерфейсов, то следовательно
>   обязан реализовать выполнение нескольких задач что никак не вяжется с
>   1 принципом

Считаю, это не следует воспринимать с фанатизмом.

Во-первых, как сказал @АлексейШиманский, Если у интерфейса задача "чтение", то он и должен "читать". А у класса задача - работа с json строками, например.

Во-вторых, классы, которые взаимозависимы друг от друга, не могут быть разделены по одной простой причине, что вы не сможете внедрить один в другой и наоборот одновременно. Пример:

Есть интерфейсы:

```
public interface IAuthInfo
{
    bool IsAuthorized { get; }

    IUser CurrentUser { get; }
}

public interface IAuthorizer
{
    Task<bool> LogUserInAsync(string email, SecureString password);
}
```

И их реализация:

```
public class AuthService : IAuthorizer, IAuthInfo
{
    public bool IsAuthorized => CurrentUser != null;

    public IUser CurrentUser { get; private set; }


    public async Task<bool> LogUserInAsync(string email, SecureString password)
    {
        // some actions to set CurrentUser property
    }
}
```

По факту `IAuthInfo` отвечает за текущую инфу об авторизации, `IAuthorizer` же позволяет авторизоваться. Вы не сможете разбить это на два класса, т.к вам нужно напрямую взаимодействовать из одного с другим и наоборот.

Comment: В принципе, соглашусь. Иначе любой класс состоял бы из одного единственного метода.

Comment: хороший пример!